# Java structure for mathematical tree with int nodes

Tags: java, tree

In Java, is `Tree` the best structure to represent a tree with such properties:

- all nodes are **unique** `int`s;
- the depth of a tree is given by `int d > 0`
- there is no restriction on how many children a node could have

Operations I need todo:

- iterate over the children **located on the first level down only** of any node
- add nodes
- remove a subtree, that is a node with all its children all the way down
- extract a subtree, that is locate and copy (clone) in a separate tree

Operations I do not need:

- edit nodes

Properties are just perfect for a `Tree`, so maybe there is some super implementation available in terms of performance. `XMLTree` or whatever.

Currently I'm using an array of arrays to store elements, but I find it not subtle.

Comment: any limits regarding insert / delete / search operations?
what about duplicate entries?

Comment: I'd probably create a class to represent a node. The class would have an int field with the value and an `ArrayList` of children nodes. There are graph libraries that will do this for you but unless you need to be worried about performance or multi-threading, it's probably quickest to roll your own.

Comment: I will insert/delete/search constantly. Actually, nothing to search, I know nodes in advance by their unique representation and just get them from the tree altogether with its children. No duplicates.

Comment: I'm worried about performance.

Comment: It's still probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of a `Node` class that could be used to form your tree structure.  There is some complexity in writing methods to iterate over all child nodes in a depth-first or breadth-first fashion.

As an alternative you could consider using [`DefaultMutableTreeNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) which provides these methods for free ([`depthFirstEnumeration()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#depthFirstEnumeration%28%29), [`breadthFirstEnumeration()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#breadthFirstEnumeration%28%29)).  This node implementation also allows you to attach a user object by calling [`setUserObject(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#setUserObject%28java.lang.Object%29).  The drawback is that the implementation may not be as compact as writing your own structure, so it really depends on the size of your tree.

```
public class Node {
  private final int value;
  private final List<Node> children;

  public Node(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.children = new LinkedList<Node>();
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public List<? extends Node> getChildren() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
  }

  public void addChild(Node child) { 
    children.add(child);
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgotten to mention, now edited about the iteration - only children on the next level down by the tree.